# PowerShell strange execution error

Tags: powershell

I've created sample cmdlet as a [file.ps1](http://pastebin.com/vVtMqJ47) with logic to check my new inbox emails iterative on required time. But when OS Task scheduler (Windows 7) executed it I get these errors:

```
The interface is unknown. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706B5)At
C:\SCRIPTS\my-userAgent.ps1:7 char:7
+ while($ie.busy -eq $true)
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a
method named 'Navigate'.At C:\SCRIPTS\my-userAgent.ps1:18 char:2
+     $ie.Navigate($url)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Navigate:String) [], RuntimeE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

As far as I understand that they are caused by my COM_obj, **But** why when I execute the same script from *PowerShell_ISE* it passes and works without errors!?! I've tried to resolve it by:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
```

hoping that is user_privileges related, but no success so far.

- Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your task started under a specific user account?

Comment: No, same user for both file.ps1 and ISE...The account has admin privileges.

Comment: Found this which seems related to your problem: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/fd6639de-73dc-4123-a6d4-ecbeb94e6ded/calling-internetexplorerapplication-from-powershell-running-as-a-scheduled-task?forum=ITCG

Comment: Post the code of my-userAgent.ps1. Specially the part where you are creating $ie object.

Comment: It's posted - line 7, please read...first line of the question

Comment: It's not the same file for sure - in the script that you've posted link to there is no `while($ie.busy -eq $true)` that you get first error from.

Comment: It's the same but older version. The problem is again in COM_Obj. But this can't explain why it's running smoothly with ISE for all the same user_account !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error, at least the first part:

> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> ```

I found that though the application window was not open, the process was still active holding the file handle. In my case it was Excel. In Task manager I killed the process and my script ran normally.